# Referencing WCF service from WP8 background agent

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8, background-agent

I have stumbled upon a problem referencing WCF service from Windows Phone background agent.

I have two projects in my solution

1. Windows Phone App
2. Background agent

I'm referencing two services in my WP app. I want the background agent to periodically call method from on of the services.

However when I add service reference to the agent I get this error

> Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'ServiceReferences.ClientConfig'. Source files: ...\Client\WPClient\WPClient\ServiceReferences.ClientConfig
>   ...\Client\WPClient\WPTaskAgent\ServiceReferences.ClientConfig

Is there a way to get rid of this error or work around it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the name of the file ServiceReferences.ClientConfig to [projectName]_ServiceReferences.ClientConfig within the class library worked for me.

Comment: The project now builds, but when the task fires I get an error, because he cannot find the config file.

Comment: My bad, all that I needed to do was to copy the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file into my PeriodicTask project and delete it from the main project.